# Preview Deployments Unavailable Publicly Even After Disabling Access Policy on a Cloudflare Pages Site

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-zero-trust

I had accidentally enabled "Access Policy" on a Cloudflare Pages site. Later, I was able to successfully delete it via the [API call mentioned in the documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/access-policies-delete-an-access-policy). I correctly get an empty `policies` array when I [list Access applications](https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/access-applications-list-access-applications).

However, my preview deployments are **still** locked behind a one-time login code. Moreover, now even if I click the "Enable access policy" button (just to test), nothing happens. It keeps loading indefinitely, and when I refresh the page, the policy is still not enabled.

It seems to be stuck in a manner that it has neither properly disabled the policy (which is what I require), nor does it let me enable it again.

Here's what I see in the application's settings:
[image: Access policy section in application settings]

This is what I see when trying to access a preview deployment:
[image: Cloudflare Access login page]

How can I make my preview deployments public?